# I would like to understand how overriding a set C struct is possible?

Tags: c, apache, apache-modules

In building a module for Apache web server, I have encountered several instances where the declaration of a structure says that it only takes `const char*` members as in the declaration of `apr_table_t` and `apr_array_header_t`, but examples I am finding in various modules such as mod_security, and even the new `ap_parse_form_data` function indicate that a `void *` data type is being inserted into these structures.

My questions are how is this possible and why will my Visual Studio compiler complain if I attempt to use the same method?

A good example of this is mod_security with a create_request function that stores a `void *` in a `request_rec` note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are *convertible*, and every object pointer type is convertible to `void*`, in the sense that storing any pointer in a `void*` doesn't lose information. That is to say, the following is valid:

```
struct Foo a;
struct Foo * p = &a;   // p points to a

void * q = p;          // OK, can store the value of p in q

struct Foo * r = q;    // OK too - we can go back, and r points to a

r->n = 1;
```

Thus it is customary in C to pass around pointers as `void*`, knowing that those can always hold *any* other object pointer value, and only cast it back to the desired type when needed.

One final word about `char` pointers in particular: Casting *any* object pointer to `char*` and actually dereferencing it as a pointer to an array of chars does *not* constitute type punning and is not a violation of the strict aliasing rule -- this simply allows you to access the underlying binary representation of any object.

Comment: Is it my compiler then? When I attempted to use the same exact code to figure out the process the compiler complained bitterly that the definition of the function I was using only accepted apr_table_t*,const char*,const char*. I did not attempt to compile the code on windows but have done so on Linux many times.

Comment: @AlexErwin: Can you post some actual code, along with the error you are experiencing?

Comment: I am unsure how to do that on here because the code is plentiful. However a snippet of the structure of apr_table_t `struct apr_table_entry_t {
    char *key;
    char *val;
    apr_uint32_t key_checksum;
};` I am not in a position to duplicate the error right at the moment, but when I perform this function `APR_DECLARE(void) apr_table_set(apr_table_t *t, const char *key,
                                const char *val);` with a variable typed as void* the compiler balks and says that I am unable to do that. Could it be that it because I am using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @AlexErwin: Yes, it could. C and C++ are different languages. It's like translating an Italian source with a Spanish dictionary.